# error: cannot refresh: cannot prepare snap-declaration refresh for snap "{SNAP}": snap-declaration ({...}; series:16) not found

Tags: updates, snap, 22.04

so I was trying to refresh snaps using **sudo snap refresh** command but it results in
`error: cannot refresh: cannot prepare snap-declaration refresh for snap "{SNAP}": snap-declaration ({...}; series:16) not found` while it was working 2 days ago...

- Please note that I tried https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snap-refresh-fails/10026 but it didn't work...

---

### System Specifications

- Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04
- Life cycle: LTS
- Architecture: AMD64
- Gnome Version: 42.0
- Windowing System: Wayland
- snapd version: 2.55.3+22.04ubuntu1

Answer (score 0):

After reinstalling snapd it worked...
and my personal guess is "As my computer is breached, the f*lthy attacker did this on snapd to stop canonical-livepatchd updates just like what he did with many other security packages!!!"